# Dual vertical monitors messes my desktop

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, monitor

When I enable my two monitors in vertical positions

[image]

My desktop files get dispersed vertically among both screens and the file icons on the upper screen are displaced, they look like they are cropped

[image]

The black space on the upper screen is due to the resolution difference.

How can I automatically arrange my icons in the lower screen only and in a proper way ? I tried right-clicking on the screen and choosing to "**Organize desktop by name**" but it didn't do the trick.